# Cannot get started with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to follow some recipes I have seen but I am missing something fundamental and cannot even get out of the box :(.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=mt_sim&p1=Erro…2Fmaster.jlbprof.com%2Fmt_sim%2Fscripts%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)
```

I am using Linux and Apache here is the layout of my directories:

```
$ tree mt_sim
mt_sim
├── img
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── controller
│   │   └── mt_sim.js
│   └── vendor
│       ├── angular.min.js
│       ├── angular.min.js.map
│       ├── angular-route.min.js
│       └── angular-route.min.js.map
├── styles
│   └── mt_sim.css
└── view
```

Here is mt_sim/index.html

```
 <html ng-app="mt_sim">
    <head>
        <script src="/mt_sim/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/mt_sim/scripts/controller/mt_sim.js"></script>
        <link href="/mt_sim/styles/mt_sim.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=outer_div ng-controller="mt_sim_contoller_1">
            <div id=inner_left_div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id=inner_right_div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Coke</li>
                    <li>Pepsi</li>
                    <li>RC Cola</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

mt_sim.js

```
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt-sim', []);

function mt_sim_controller_1 ($scope)
{
}
```

mt_sim.css

```
#outer_div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inner_left_div {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
}

#inner_right_div = {
    width: 83%;
}
```

This is so frustrating but I have no idea where to go from here.

Thanx

Bodger

Comment: problem is not from css file, css file is not related to this exception. This exception is caused by Angular can't find your module, check src of mt_sim.js!

Comment: PS Did you close the `<link>` tag?

Comment: link is closed. I must have missed it while copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I am a dummy.

```
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt-sim', []);
```

Should be:

```
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt_sim', []);
```

In index.html I did:

```
<html ng-app="mt_sim">
```

I feel like an idiot.

Thanx everyone for your help.

Bodger

Comment: there is two way to declare a module:
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt-sim', []);
or
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt-sim');
The first way to include another module which is assigned for your module. The second one is declare a new module standalone.

Answer (score 4):

```
var mt_sim = angular.module ('mt-sim', []);

function mt_sim_controller_1 ($scope)
{
}
```

should be

```
var mt_sim = angular.module('mt-sim', []);

mt_sim.controller("mt_sim_controller_1", function($scope) {
  $scope.whatever = "something";
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm new to Angular. Thanks!

Comment: It still errors out the same way:Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=mt_sim&p1=Erro…2Fmaster.jlbprof.com%2Fmt_sim%2Fscripts%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)

Comment: I don't think so! function body can be null! hey @Bodger, I think you should have a try with my answer. This way is not right. function body can be nothing inside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the problem from your path to js file. I made a a sample as same you but with different path for my js file. With as same as angular.js, mt_sim.js, css file and jsp. But you must consider about Deploy Assembly, check Deploy Assembly to see how your project deploy with individual path, when your project is built and deploy it will wrap your file with only /mt_sim/... So if must define source of js file like this:

```
<html ng-app="mt_sim">
    <head>
        <script type="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="js/mt_sim.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=outer_div ng-controller="mt_sim_contoller_1">
            <div id=inner_left_div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id=inner_right_div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Coke</li>
                    <li>Pepsi</li>
                    <li>RC Cola</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It run for me:
[image: Demo for mt_sim]
I tested it and it run properly. I definitely confirmed that your problem come from source of js file not css file. Give a try and good luck[image: Project Structure]